# How to highlight the python matching list elements?

Tags: python, list, compare, highlight, matching

I have successfully compared two lists and could get the matching elements but the output i need should display 1st list with its elements highlighting the matching element. Example:

```
list1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
list2 = [e,f,g,h,i,j,k]

output = [a,b,c,d,/e/,/f/,/g/]
```

Comment: are the letters strings?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem? That will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming! I got the answer!@GileadKenzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is efficient but as per what your output say we can do something like this. Also I assumed that there are strings inside list.

```
>>> list1
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> list2
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
>>> list3 = list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
>>> list3
['e', 'g', 'f']
>>> for i in list3:
...     list1[list1.index(i)] = '/'+i+'/'
... 
>>> list1
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '/e/', '/f/', '/g/']
>>>
```

Comment: Consider accepting this if you find this as your answer. :)

Comment: theres a problem, your code works fine for a single list. but i have multiple lists, when it compares with second list, the second list output gets updated with first one's list.
Example:
The next list has only c as matching one, the output should be
 list1 = [a,b,/c/,d,e,f,g] but instead the output is 
list1 = [a,b,/c/,d,/e/,/f/,/g/].
 can you help? @Shashank

Comment: Is it possible if you can create another duplicate list and then try to highlight it. In that way your original list will not be changed and you will get the answer. In my answer I tried to modify the list1 which is the original one. You can try list3 = list1[:] and then in for loop use list3.

Comment: I have 5 lists generated internally and got a list from the user , so totally 6 lists with different alphabets. I compared users list with the internal list and has matching percentage.I need to output the lists with descending order of matching percentage.
For eg: 
My output is

`Users list : [a,b,c,d,e]
list 1 matches 20% : [/a/,b,c,d,e]
list 3 matches 80% : [/a/,/b/,/c/,/d/,e] 
list 5 matches 60% : [/a/,/b/,/c/,d,e]`
The output should be
`Users list : [a,b,c,d,e]
list 3 matches 80% : [/a/,/b/,/c/,/d/,e] 
list 5 matches 60% : [/a/,/b/,/c/,d,e]
list 1 matches 20% : [/a/,b,c,d,e]`

Comment: Can you be more specific like where you are facing problem ? What's your progress till now to get the desired solution ? Also It would be great if you can open one new question for this as you might get much better answers.

Comment: New question might get marked as broad, so I didn't open. The problem is I need to sort the lists based on percentages without affecting the lists and its elements. The list1(randomly generated) with its elements matches 5 elements with the user's list that has 10 elements(so 50% match). Likewise the list2 matches 7(70% match). List3 matches 3(30% match).  I need to display first, the highest percentage matching list, that is, list2 then list1 then list3 without changing any elements of respective lists.

Comment: Hope you can help me:)

Comment: See what you can do is:
1. Compare with user list and get result and append to the same list for sorting. Like make for loop and check if this in that ...
2. After doing everything your list will be like [/a/, /b/, 50] (showing 50% value). Now append this to any new list for sort later on by:
new_list.sort(reverse = True, key = lambda x: x[-1])

Now you will get your sorted list. Now pop those last value from every list and now you got your list sorted in ascending order. I highly recommend you to ask question because there can be one line answer for this but not sure how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = list('abcdefg')
list2 = list('efghijk')
result = ['/{}/'.format(l) if l in list2 else l for l in list1]
print(result)
```

Comment: If you've found an acceptable answer mark as answer or share with us what your are missing from your requirements.

Comment: I marked the "answer". Thanks!, I didn't know about it @EyueIDK

Answer (score 0):

You can't highlight elements, but you could capitalise:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
list2 = ['e','f','i','j','k','a']

common = [i.upper() for i in list1 if i in list2]
notCommon = [i for i in list(set(list1+list2)) if i.upper() not in common]

output = common+notCommon

print output
```

Returns:

> ['A', 'E', 'F', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'i', 'k', 'j']

Comment: Thanks for the help @Robbie